# "surprising" constant initialization because of definition order

Tags: c++, initialization, constants, c++11, constexpr

When reading the [slides about constexpr](http://accu.org/content/conf2007/Maurer-C++0x_Generating_Constant_Expression.pdf) the introduction is about *"surprisingly dynamic initialization with consts"*. The example is

```
struct S {
    static const int c;
};
const int d = 10 * S::c;
const int S::c = 5;
```

Alas, the audio track is missing, so are the notes, so I can only guess what is meant here.

**Is it corrrect that `d` is "surprisingly" initialized dynamically, because `S::c` is defined *before* `d`?** That the *declaration* of `S::c` is before `d` is probably not enough, the compiler needs the complete *definition*, right?

That said, I suspect, that in the following example **`d` *would* be initialized statically?**

```
struct S {
    static const int c;
};
const int S::c = 5;
const int d = 10 * S::c;  // now _after_ defn of S::c
```

And to take the cake, in C++11, **what would have to be `constexpr`** for full static initialization? `S::c`, `d` or both?

Comment: Static members can be declared anywhere in the source file.

Comment: I would suspect `d` is `0` in the case presented in the slides, as if I recall correctly static memory is 0-initialized before it is set to its expected value.

Comment: @vivek the place of _declaration_ is fixed anyway, but the place of initialization is not. While it feels unnatural to me too this should matter for static const`s, we must keep in mind that C++ is not Haskell.

Comment: @vivik: Yes of course. But I think you mean *"defined"*, do you? And even so, that does not relate to my question about *static* or *dynamic* initialization...

Comment: @leftaroundabout: ...but with `constexpr` it almost becomes it ;-)

Comment: By *declare* I meant *declare space*

Answer (score 3):

In the first example, `d` is not initialized by a constant expression, because `S::c` is not

> a non-volatile const object with a preceding initialization,
>   initialized with a constant expression

(see C++11 [expr.const]p2, bullet on lvalue-to-rvalue conversions), because the initialization of `S::c` does not precede the initialization of `d`. Therefore static initialization will be used for `S::c` (because it is initialized by a constant expression), but dynamic initialization can be used for `d`.

Since static initialization precedes dynamic initialization, `d` would be initialized to `50` by its dynamic initializer. The compiler is permitted to convert the dynamic initialization of `d` to static initialization, but if it does, it must produce the value that `d` would have had if every variable which could have used dynamic initialization had, in fact, used dynamic initialization. In this case, `d` is initialized to `50` either way. See C++11 [basic.start.init]p2 for more information on this.

There is no way to add `constexpr` to the first example to guarantee that static initialization is used for `d`; in order to do that, you must reorder the initializations. However, adding `constexpr` will produce a diagnostic for the first example, which will at least allow you to ensure that dynamic initialization is *not* used (you get static initialization or a compilation error).

You can update the second case to ensure that static initialization is used as follows:

```
struct S {
    static const int c; // do not use constexpr here
};
constexpr int S::c = 5;
constexpr int d = 10 * S::c;
```

It is ill-formed to use `constexpr` on a variable declaration which is not a definition, or to use it on a variable declaration which does not contain an initializer, so `const`, not `constexpr` must be used within the definition of `struct S`. There is one exception to this rule, which is when defining a `static constexpr` data member of a literal, non-integral type, with the initializer specified within the class:

```
struct T { int n; };
struct U {
    static constexpr T t = { 4 };
};
constexpr T U::t;
```

In this case, `constexpr` must be used in the definition of the class, in order to permit an initializer to be provided, and `constexpr` must be used in the definition of the static data member, in order to allow its use within constant expressions.

Comment: Exactly. I wanted to understand the a/the  reason behind the new `constexpr`. Thus, I wanted to make sure that I got a good reason for `constexpr` here. You confirmed my understanding.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the rules laid out in 3.6.2 to determine when *static initialization* happens do not include the initialization for `d`, which is therefore *dynamic initialization*. On the other hand, `S::c` is indeed statically initialized (since `5` is a constant expression). Since all static initialization happens before dynamic initialization, you get the expected result.

To make `d` eligible for static initialization, it has to be initialized with a constant expression. This in turn forces you to write the `S::c` inline:

```
struct S { static constexpr int c = 5; };

const int d = S::c; // statically initialized
```

Note that the standard permits dynamic initialization to be replaced by static initialization, which is why reordering the two lines in your original example will cause the two different sorts of initialization. As TonyK points out, you can use `array[d]` in the static case, but not in the dynamic case, so you can check which one is happening. With the `constexpr` approach, you're guaranteed to have static initialization and you don't have to rely on optional compiler behaviour.

Comment: "_Note that the standard permits dynamic initialization to be replaced by static initialization_" Can you show the relevant standard text?

Comment: An implementation is permitted to perform the initialization of a non-local variable with static storage duration as a static initialization even if such initialization is not required to be done statically, provided that
— the dynamic version of the initialization does not change the value of any other object of namespace
scope prior to its initialization, and
— the static version of the initialization produces the same value in the initialized variable as would be
produced by the dynamic initialization if all variables not required to be initialized statically were
initialized dynamically.

Comment: "_so you can check which one is happening._" No you can't.

Comment: @curiousguy: What's the problem? The declaration `char a[d];` will compile if `d` can be initialized statically, which works in one of the two cases but not the other, even though according to the standard, `d` is never guaranteed to be statically initialized.

Comment: So you are not saying that `d` is a constant expression iff `d` happens to be initialized statically? Can you show an example where `d` is not guaranteed to be statically initialized, but `int a[d];` is legal?

Answer (score 2):

For static initialization one needs, roughly speaking, a constant-expression initializer.

To be a constant-expression, roughly speaking, a variable needs to be of a `const` type and have a preceding initialization with a constant-expression.

In the first example `d`'s initializer is not a constant-expression, as `S::c` isn't one (it has no preceding initialization). Hence, `d` is not statically initialized.

In the second example `d`'s initializer is a constant-expression, and everything is OK.

I'm simplifying matters. In full formal standardese this would be about nine times longer.

---

As for `constexpr` specifier, no object **has** to be declared `constexpr`. It is just an additional error-check. (This is about `constexpr` *objects*, not `constexpr` *functions*).

You *may* declare `S::c` `constexpr` in the second variant if you want some extra error protection (perhaps 5 will start changing its value tomorrow?) Adding `constexpr` to the first variant cannot possibly help.

Comment: As an additional "error check"? Checking what? You probably mean "checking if dynamic initialization is possible", do you?

Comment: @towi: No, I mean "checking if this is indeed a constant expression, as suggested by the mnemonics of `constexpr`".

Answer (score 1):

You can find out whether a constant is statically or dynamically initialised by trying to declare an array:

```
struct S {
    static const int c;
};
const int d = 10 * S::c; // (1)
const int S::c = 5;      // (2)

static char array[d];
```

This code fails in g++ version 4.7.0, because `d` is dynamically initialised. And if you exchange (1) and (2), it compiles, because now `d` is statically initialised. But I can't find another way to fix it, using `constexpr`.

Comment: Hmm, I think there was a late change in `constexpr`. First a definition could only depend on previous *definitions* in the same file. I though this had changed later in the process to a more general approach, but I am not sure. Maybe gcc just has not learned this yet?

Comment: This replacement of dynamic by static initialization is explicitly allowed by the standard (3.6.2). There's even an example in there where this replacement produced unspecified behaviour.

Comment: @TonyK: of course the problem with the `array[d]` diagnosis utility is when you're definition large constants (build timestamp, for example...)

Comment: @Matthieu: Then just say `static char array[d & 15] ;` instead.

Comment: `static_assert( sizeof(int[d]), "" );` works and involves no actual object.